# What versions of cobertura and surefire plugins work together under maven3?

Tags: maven-3, cobertura, maven-surefire-plugin

What versions of **cobertura** and **surefire** plugins work together under **maven3**?

After switching to maven3 I've found out, that `mvn cobertura:cobertura` is no longer generating report about test coverage (the coverage displayed is 0%). It was working under maven2...

However, after finding, that in one of the other projects reports are still working, I've analysed the effective pom. After finding out I was using other versions of plugins, I've downgraded `maven-surefire-plugin` from version 2.8 to 2.4.3. I'm using `maven-cobertura-plugin` in version 2.5.1.

This is a working solution, however the plugin versions I use are quite old, but I don't want to experiment until I find the working pair of version. So, my question is, what is causing the incompatibility between this two plugins? Is it a bug or the behaviour of the plugins have changed between versions in the way that made them incompatibile? Where to find the information about plugin compatibility, and not the plugin itself?

Comment: I have a project which does not have explicit plugin declaration for either surefire or cobertura.  It works fine for me with `maven-3.0.4`. From the logs, I see that `2.10` version of surefire and `2.5.1` version of cobertura is being used.

Comment: After a few runs, coverage failed to 0 for plugin 2.4.3. I've upgraded to 2.11, this what I changed is I changed fork mode from 'never' to 'once'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010428/is-the-surefires-forkmode-never-working-with-cobertura-under-maven-3/11952132#11952132). Basically `forkMode=never` is not guaranteed to work with cobertura and was only working by accident in older versions of Maven.